# NestJS - GraphQL project can't be initialized

Tags: node.js, graphql, node-modules, apollo, nestjs

I'm working on a project which uses React, NestJS, Urql and GraphQL. All project was working correctly but now project cannot being initialized. Actual project was initializing like this capture:

[image: Correctly started project capture]

But now project stucks here for 1-2 weeks:

[image: Stucked while starting capture]

And I've no idea if it is about this but nest started to throw this error after it started to being not initialized, I've added "esModuleInterop: true" flag to tsconfig then error has gone but it stucked on initializing section as it shown on second picture:

[image: Web socket error]

Answer (score 0):

My node version was 14 and downgraded to 12, now it's solved!